# include tablesorter plugin backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, tablesorter

tablesorter plugin duplicates data added to table from input form and then sorts by clicking on header that duplicated data. after page refresh table shows entered data in order of entrance

can anyone help with this 
http://jsfiddle.net/KrRyb/

thanks

```
window.BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "tr",

events: {
},

template: $("#book-item").template(),

initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this, "render");
},

render: function(){
  var element = jQuery.tmpl(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
  $(this.el).html(element);
  return this;
  }
  });
  $(document).ready(function() 
  { 
    $("#books-table").tablesorter(); 
  } 
  ); 
window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#app"),
events: {
  "click .tabs a": "tabs",
        "click #add-book": "createBook",
        "click .edit-book": "editBook",
        "click #update-book": "updateBook",         
        "click .delete-book": "deleteBook",
        "click #selectall": "selectAllBooks",
        "click .select": "selectBookRow",   
        "click #manage tbody tr": "selectBookRow",
        "click #deleteall": "deleteAll"                                                 
},

initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this, "render", "tabs", "addAll", "addBook", "createBook", "editBook",                "deleteBook");
        this.activeBookId = null;
        this.$("#create").show();
  Books.bind('add', this.addBook); 
  Books.bind('reset', this.addAll);
  Books.fetch();
},

selectAllBooks: function(el){
    var target = $(el.target), rows = this.$('#manage tr:not(#select-info)');
        if(target.is(':checked'))
        {
                 rows.css({background:"whiteSmoke"}).find('.select').prop("checked", true);
        }
        else
        {
             rows.css({background:"white"}).find('.select').prop("checked", false);
        }
        this.showSelected();
    },

    selectBookRow: function(el){
        var target = $(el.target), row = target.parents("tr"), checkbox =  row.find('.select');
        if(checkbox.is(':checked'))
        {
            row.css({background:"white"});
            checkbox.prop("checked", false);
        }
        else
        {
            row.css({background:"whiteSmoke"});
            checkbox.prop("checked", true);
        }
        this.showSelected();            
    },      

    showSelected: function(){
        var info = $('#select-info'), count = $('#manage     .select:checked').length, word = count>1?"books":"book",
            html = '<tr id="select-info"><td colspan="6">('+count+')   '+word+' selected. <a id="deleteall" href="javascript:void(0);">delete</a></td></tr>';
        if(Books.length>0)
        {
            if(info.length === 0)
            {
              $('#manage tbody').prepend(html); 
            }
            else if(count>0)
            {
                info.replaceWith($(html));
            }
            else
            {
                info.remove();
            }
        }   
    },

    deleteAll: function(){  
        $('#manage tbody').find('input:checked').each(function() {
            var that = $(this);
            Books.get(that.data('id')).destroy();
            that.parents('tr').remove();
        });
        $('#select-info').hide();
        $('#selectall').prop("checked", false);
    },

    tabs: function(e){
      var target = $(e.target);
      $('.tabs a').removeClass('active');
      target.addClass('active');
      this.$('.content').hide();
      if(target.attr('id') === "create-tab")
      {
        this.$("#create").show();   
      }
      else
      { 
          this.addAll();
            this.$('#selectall').prop("checked", false);
        this.$("#manage").show();       
      }
    },

    editBook: function(el){
        var target = $(el.target), book = Books.get(target.data('id'));
        this.activeBookId = target.data('id');
        $('#book-edit-form').find(':input[name]:enabled').each(function() {
            var self = $(this);
            self.val(book.attributes[self.attr('name')]);
        });
        this.$('.content').hide();
        this.$('#manage-edit').show();
    },

    updateBook: function(el){
        var target = $(el.target), data = {};
        $('#book-edit-form').find(':input[name]:enabled').each(function() {
            var self = $(this);
            data[self.attr('name')] = self.val();
        });
        Books.get(this.activeBookId).set(data).save();
        this.addAll();
        this.$('.content').hide();
        this.$('#manage').show();
    },

    deleteBook: function(el){
        var target = $(el.target);
        Books.get(target.data('id')).destroy();
        target.parents('tr').remove();
    },      

  addAll: function(){
      this.$("#manage table tbody").empty();    
    Books.each(this.addBook)
  },

  addBook: function(book){
    var view = new BookView({model: book});
    this.$("#manage table tbody").prepend(view.render().el);
  },

   createBook: function(e){
        var data = {};
        $('#book-form').find(':input[name]:enabled').each(function() {
            var self = $(this);
            data[self.attr('name')] = self.val();
            self.val("");
        });
        Books.create(data);
  }
   });

    window.App = new AppView();

   window.AppController = Backbone.Router.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    $('.tabs a').removeClass('active');
    this.mainView = new window.AppView
  },

  routes: {
    "create":"create",
    "books":"books"
  },

  create: function() {
    $('.tabs a#create').addClass('active');
  },

  books: function() {
    $('.tabs a#books').addClass('active');
  }

      });

     window.App = new AppController();
     Backbone.history.start();

     });
```

Comment: Your fiddle won't work like that, you can't just include local files and expect anyone else to have them.
And, are you expecting tablesorter to maintain the sorting you've selected after refresh? That won't ever work unless you save the setting to server or local storage.

Comment: i need only temporary sorting when i view my table data

Comment: Then you need to improve the wording of your question or make your jsFiddle work, or both.

Comment: i cant get jsFiddle to work. this is download link..    <<<https://github.com/seogrady/backbone-books>>>   -example for download. How to implement tablesorter with paginator to table in example. i am trying to learn and make something but need some help thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to guess the problem you're having, but I think if you put the tablesorter initialization code after the template renders, it might work...

so change this:

```
    render: function(){
      var element = jQuery.tmpl(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
      $(this.el).html(element);
      return this;
    }
  });
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#books-table").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
);
```

to this:

```
    render: function(){
      var element = jQuery.tmpl(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
      $(this.el).html(element);
      // initialize tablesorter here
      $("#books-table").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} );
      return this;
    }
  });
```

Comment: it duplicates data. for example, if i have 3 rows it adds them one more time so i have 6, and sorts that duplicated rows. after refresh returns to previous state of table (3 rows)

Comment: Are you updating the table contents? And if you are, are you using the update method, or just re-initializing the table?

Comment: table updates on each table add and on each table content edit

Comment: Yes, but are you using `$("#books-table").trigger("update");`?